# Response.redirect puts extra characters in the url Error 400

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I am trying to use response.redirect on a button click event server side but it gives me http 400 bad request error. I was not getting this error before but I just moved the projectto vs 2010 framework 4.0 and I started getting this error. 
This is what I am writing:

```
 protected void bOrganizationAddID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyURL;
        MyURL = "addNewPopup.aspx?orgID=" + this.OrganizationID;

        Response.Redirect(MyURL);



    }
```

and when i try to build it, the url shown on the page with error is : 
http://localhost:2504/padrap/pages/admin/%2fpadrap%2fpages%2fadmin%2faddNewPopup.aspx%3forgID%3d33

instead of being just:
localhost:2504/padrap/pages/admin/addNewPopup.aspx?orgID=33

Can anyone help me out here please. How do I get the redirect to take me to the correct url?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think this is a bug in 4.0 or something, as I tried everything. The workaround is this though:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
           "redirectFixOrg", string.Format("document.location = '{0}?orgID={1}'",
           this.ResolveClientUrl("~/pages/admin/addNewPopup.aspx"), this.OrganizationID), true);
```

This worked for me but I dont know why response.redirect is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try-- Server.UrlEncode(this.OrganizationID)