# Response.Redirect is improperly URL-encoding the destination URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response.redirect

In an old VB.NET website, there is a page in the admin section with a URL like `http://example.com/Admin/EditUser.aspx`. At the end of the event handler for the submit button on that page, it tries to redirect to itself with an added query string, like so: `Response.Redirect("EditUser.aspx?a=b")`. This causes my browser to try to redirect to `http://example.com/Admin/%2fAdmin%2fEditUser.aspx%3fa%3db`, which is wrong. If I prepend `~/` to the Response.Redirect call, it redirects to `http://example.com/Admin/%2fEditUser.aspx%3fa%3db`, which is still wrong. Even if I remove the query string from the redirect URL, Response.Redirect still adds a superfluous `%2f`.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Edit: This guy had the same issue and concludes it's a bug in .NET 4.0: [Response.redirect puts extra characters in the url Error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105293/response-redirect-puts-extra-characters-in-the-url-error-400)

His workaround involves using `document.location` in Javascript. But I would still like to know how to solve this on the server side.

Comment: Might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472150/response-redirect-occasionally-ignores-url-encoding

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. Even if I try to redirect to `https://wwww.google.com`, it isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in Response.Redirect that was caused by the submit button being contained in an `UpdatePanel`. The solution was to add a `<Triggers>` section to the `UpdatePanel` like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />  
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- ...Content goes here... --%>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This was driving me nuts, so I hope it helps somebody.